# Auto Increment by Column and by Group

Tags: mysql, sql

I search everywhere. I can't find my want.

**My current Schema with data | Table Name ["mini_sales"]**

| id (auto increment) | transactionid | totalpayment | totalchange | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 2 | NULL | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 3 | NULL | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 4 | NULL | 200 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:56:00 |
| 5 | NULL | 200 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:56:00 |
| 6 | NULL | 300 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:58:00 |

**I want table_schema like this:**

| id (auto increment) | transactionid | totalpayment | totalchange | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 | 20 | 08/01/2022 13:52:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 200 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:56:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 200 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:56:00 |
| 6 | 3 | 300 | 10 | 08/01/2022 13:58:00 |

I tried creating one [Select], but I can't comprehend it well.

```
select * 
from mini_sales 
GROUP by totalpayment, totalchange, date 
order by id, date
```

Comment: Your query is just selecting data that's already in the table, it won't change `transactionid`. And you need aggregation functions when you use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Join with a subquery that use the `RANK()` window function.

Comment: @ErgestBasha That seems to be a coincidence. I'm pretty sure he wants to increment transaction ID when the date changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the window function `DENSE_RANK#`

> ```
> SELECT
> `id`,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY `date` ) `transactionid`, `totalpayment`, `totalchange`, `date`
> FROM Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | transactionid | totalpayment | totalchange | date               
> -: | ------------: | -----------: | ----------: | :------------------
>  1 |             1 |         1000 |          20 | 2022-08-01 15:52:00
>  2 |             1 |         1000 |          20 | 2022-08-01 15:52:00
>  3 |             1 |         1000 |          20 | 2022-08-01 15:52:00
>  4 |             2 |          200 |          10 | 2022-08-01 15:56:00
>  5 |             2 |          200 |          10 | 2022-08-01 15:56:00
>  6 |             3 |          300 |          10 | 2022-08-01 15:58:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=610216e0e3dc8160eca315e6394f750e)*